# Access a return parameter type array of a method

Tags: c#, arrays, return

I have a class `Cars` and in the method `get_cars()` I create multiple `Cars` and return them as an array `cars`. In my class `Home`, I have the method `main()` where I want to work with the array "cars". In the example I just want to write the name of every car. But it seems like the `name` attribute is empty. What did I do wrong?

```
class Car
{
    //only one attribute for test
    public string name;
    // public string color;
    // public string brand;

    public car()
    {
    }

    //create multiple Car, limited to 2 for the test und return them in an array
    public static Car[] get_cars()
    {
        Car[] cars = new Car[2];
        for (int k = 0; k<cars.Length; k++)
        {
            cars[k] = new Car();
            cars[k].name = "Car 0" + k;
        }
        return cars;
    }
}

class Home
{
    private void Main()
    {
        Car[] cars = new Car[2];
        cars = Car.get_cars();

        cars[0] = new Car();
        //the output is empty, it seems that cars[0].name is emtpy;
        set_label_header(cars[0].name);

        cars[1] = new Car();

        //the output is empty, it seems that cars[1].name is emtpy;
        set_label_header(cars[1].name);

        //that works
        set_label_header("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nuffin Changing code, while it makes this work: Shouldn't be done. The typos/errors could be the cause of the issue.

Comment: @FrankerZ The way the question is formulated implies this is a runtime issue and the code was just badly copied (and it still doesn't compile because I missed the `Car` ctor). Otherwise I would agree.

Comment: Google method naming convention in C#.

Answer (score 6):

> But it seems like the "name" attribute is empty

It's because of the following line:

```
cars[0] = new Car();
```

The `new Car()` creates a fresh object with a clean slate and you only set its id, so `name` is empty. From the `get_cars` method you are already returning the objects instantiated, so you don't need to instantiate again.

You actually don't need to new it up.

The following code is fair enough for your case:

```
Car[] cars = Car.get_cars();
```

and then call your method :

```
set_label_header(cars[0].name);
```

Comment: How about the obvious typos `Cr` or `privte`?

Comment: @FrankerZ typos in ?

Answer (score 2):

You are generating new empty Car object here:

```
cars[0] = new Car();
cars[1] = new Car();
```

You should access the cars array directly without creating new object.

```
cars[0].name
```

Answer (score 1):

You're re-creating the objects in your array with the `new` command. Change your `Main` method as follows:

```
void Main() 
{ 
    Car[] cars = Car.get_cars();
    set_label_header(cars[0].name);
    set_label_header(cars[1].name);
}
```